# How to inject static field's value into constructor

Tags: spring

I want to inject `System.out` in the constuctor of X:

```
@Component
public class XImpl implements X {

  PrintStream stream;

  @Autowired
  public XImpl(@Qualifier("...")PrintStream stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
  }
}
```

How do you do that, with a qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

In XML configuration it's easy, use `util:const` tag.

In annotation config, you might be able to do it using [`@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) combined with [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), something like:

```
@Value("#{T(java.lang.System).out}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a bean name "sysout" in your main class:

```
@Bean(name = "sysout")
public PrintStream getSysOut() {
    return System.out;
}
```

Now you can inject this bean like this:

```
PrintStream stream;

@Autowired
public PrinterX(@Qualifier("sysout") PrintStream stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
}

@RequestMapping("test")
public String test(){
    stream.println("This works");
    return "tested";
}
```

This outputs "This works" in the console.